# Embeddable entities with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.2 in a Kotlin project and trying to use *Embedded* objects in Entity classes

```kotlin
import org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository
import java.io.Serializable
import javax.persistence.Embeddable
import javax.persistence.Embedded
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class TestEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long,
    @Embedded
    val emb: Emb
)

@Embeddable
class Emb(
    val field: String
)

interface TestEntityRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<TestEntity, Long>
```

So, kotlin JPA and spring plugins are used in my project:

```
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.21"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.2"
```

When I try to persist entity with the `TestEntityRepository` repository:

```kotlin
testEntityRepository.save(TestEntity(1L, Emb("asd")))
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
3:37:20.336 [main] ERROR o.s.c.e.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter - Unexpected error occurred in asynchronous listener
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Nested entities are not supported
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.writeProperties(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.writeInternal(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.write(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.write(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy.getOutboundRow(DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy.java:177)
...
```

Seems that embedding should work, why it is not working in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the stacktrace the error becomes very clear

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: **Nested
> entities are not supported**
> at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.**MappingR2dbcConverter**.writePropertyInternal(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:251)

If then you check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/r2dbc/mapping.html#mapping.conventions) it also becomes verified

> Convention-based Mapping
>
> ....
>
> Nested objects are not supported.

The solution to your problem according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/r2dbc/mapping.html#mapping.explicit.converters) is to register your own converter according to your needs which will support nested objects